# What does Application.WorksheetFunction.Find do?

Tags: excel, vbscript

Trying to convert a vbscript to php.

Have this line in the script:

```
digit = Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(aChar, PERMITTED)
```

Where aChar is a character and PERMITTED is a string.

It looks like some sort of validation, but not 100% sure.

What value will digit be? What happends if aChar is not in PERMITTED?

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198169(v=office.14).aspx) isn't very clear.

Comment: Yeah, that's some pretty obtuse documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the solidarity.

Comment: @Sifu: PERMITTED is just a variable name.

Comment: In other news, a Google Search for `WorksheetFunction.Find` has reminded me how utterly useless forums are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub fksdjhfsdjf()
    aChar = "a"
    PERMITTED = "qwertyasdf"
    digit = Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(aChar, PERMITTED)
    MsgBox digit
End Sub
```

**FIND()** will return the *position* of "a" ________________similar to **InStr()**

**EDIT#1**

Both Application.WorkSheetfunction.Find() and InStr() are *case sensitive*

If the little string does not exist within the big string, **Application.WorkSheetfunction.Find()** will raise an error and **InStr()** will return a **0.**

This is not the same as the **Range.find()** Method

Comment: Thank you! That answer seems consistent with the context of the argument. What would happen if 'a' doesn't exist in PERMITTED? (edit, clarified question)

Comment: So is `WorksheetFunction.Find` just a variation on `InStr()`?  Why not just use `InStr()`, a function which *everyone* understands?

Comment: What would happen if 'a' doesn't exist in PERMITTED?